# OAuth 2.0 Server Provider in Swift with Perfect

Tags: swift, oauth, oauth-2.0, perfect

How do I offer OAuth 2.0 provider services using swift?  I would like to use swift as a rest API but missing this integral component.  Would probably be able to build something from the spec but don't have budget on this particular project.  Would be a great component to Perfect framework but I don't see it on the roadmap at present?

Answer (score 3):

There are OAuth2 client libs: https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-OAuth2

OAuth2 demo: https://github.com/PerfectExamples/Perfect-Authentication-Demo

A work in progress OAuth2 Server: https://github.com/PerfectServers/AuthenticationServer

Comment: At this point the Perfect team strongly discourages use of Turnstile for authentication.

Comment: @Cameron can I ask why it is strongly discouraged?  I haven't worked with it.  Just curious.

Comment: Turnstile has a bug in it's core that impacts it's stability. It's also very far behind the local authentication modules in functionality.

Comment: Not to mention Stormpath (who developed the Turnstile package) was acquired by Okta and appears to no longer be developing their swift codebase (latest is 9months - 1year at this point).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any Swift based OAuth identity provider solutions yet. Found a few libraries that might either be ported or built into a Swift solution, but it seems like the simplest path at the moment would be to implement something like Auth0 or OAuth.io as the provider